# how can we implement CAN Application Layer(CAL) protocol in iphone/android

Tags: android, iphone, can-bus

I need to interface a device which is supporting CANBus ,So for communication with that I need to follow CAL,So can any one help that ho can I implement 
CAN Application Layer(CAL) protocol in iphone/android .
Please help i am not getting any way to solve it

Comment: First of all you need some hardware interface to CAN, like CAN-WLAN gateway or CAN-Bluetooth adapter etc. What are you going to use?

Comment: hi!!! @androider you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

> "I need to interface a device which is supporting CANBus ,So for
>   communication with that I need to follow CAL"

The second part of that statement doesn't follow necessarily from the first. There are plenty of devices and systems that communicate via a CAN bus that don't use a formal higher level application framework.

First, you need to be able to communicate with the can bus from your application. Your mentioning iphones suggests you'll be targeting consumer handsets, none of which will have a CAN interface. So you need to incorporate some adapter hardware (there are usb adapters, and android at least has usb hardware access baked into the SDK).

If you do then also need to communicate with components that implement a higher level application framework like CANopen on top of the CAN layer, your options are:

1. Get your hands on the specification from whatever group maintains
   it, and implement it in your language and framework of choice. This is likely a substantial effort.
2. Purchase or find an open source implementation. If you purchase the source code for a C implementation, you can compile it into a shared library for your target architecture, and, using android as an example, write a native wrapper for that shared library using the Android NDK to expose it to your java code. If you could purchase the source code for a java implementation, you might be able to port it so that it works natively on android.

Then you need to glue the data layer together with the application layer, and this will likely be custom development no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You need the hardware to support it.  I've found Gwentech's GT1026 to work well for [can bus to android](http://www.gwentechembedded.com/?product=gt1026-android-can-bus-usb-adapter), but it only works on Android using USB.